# POST http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/sendotp 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ssl

I am working on a project basically when i sign up it is supposed to send an otp on provided email but instead i am getting above mentioned error. I have previously done my testing on postman at that time it was working fine but now when i am connecting my backened and frontend and trying to send otp it is throwing error in console

SENDOTP API ERROR............

1. *AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}*

   1. **code**: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
   2. **config**: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
   3. **message**: "Request failed with status code 401"
   4. **name**: "AxiosError"
   5. **request**: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
   6. **response**: {data: {…}, status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
   7. **stack**: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:144559:12)\n at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143244:66)"
   8. [[Prototype]]: Error
2. 1. 1. 

Now when i ytry to signup it thorws error but i ecpect it to send otp on my mail

my api connector file

```
import axios from "axios"

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({});

export const apiConnector = (method, url, bodyData, headers, params) => {
    return axiosInstance({
        method:`${method}`,
        url:`${url}`,
        data: bodyData ? bodyData : null,
        headers: headers ? headers: null,
        params: params ? params : null,
    });
}

my apis file
const BASE_URL =  "https://localhost:4000/api/v1"

export const categories = {
    CATEGORIES_API: BASE_URL + "/course/showAllCategories"
}

// AUTH ENDPOINTS
export const endpoints = {
    SENDOTP_API: BASE_URL + "/auth/sendotp",
    SIGNUP_API: BASE_URL + "/auth/signup",
    LOGIN_API: BASE_URL + "/auth/login",
    RESETPASSTOKEN_API: BASE_URL + "/auth/reset-password-token",
    RESETPASSWORD_API: BASE_URL + "/auth/reset-password",
  }

my authAPI file
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast"

import { setLoading, setToken } from "../../slices/authSlice"
//import { resetCart } from "../../slices/cartSlice"
//import { setUser } from "../../slices/profileSlice"
import { apiConnector } from "../apiconnector"
import { endpoints } from "../apis"

const {
  SENDOTP_API,
  SIGNUP_API,
  LOGIN_API,
  RESETPASSTOKEN_API,
  RESETPASSWORD_API,
} = endpoints

export function sendOtp(email, navigate) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const toastId = toast.loading("Loading...")
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    try {
      const response = await apiConnector("POST", SENDOTP_API, {
        email,
        checkUserPresent: true,
      })
      console.log("SENDOTP API RESPONSE............", response)

      console.log(response.data.success)

      if (!response.data.success) {
        throw new Error(response.data.message)
      }

      toast.success("OTP Sent Successfully")
      navigate("/verify-email")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("SENDOTP API ERROR............", error)
      toast.error("Could Not Send OTP")
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false))
    toast.dismiss(toastId)
  }
}

export function signUp(
  accountType,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email,
  password,
  confirmPassword,
  otp,
  navigate
) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const toastId = toast.loading("Loading...")
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    try {
      const response = await apiConnector("POST", SIGNUP_API, {
        accountType,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        confirmPassword,
        otp,
      })

      console.log("SIGNUP API RESPONSE............", response)

      if (!response.data.success) {
        throw new Error(response.data.message)
      }
      toast.success("Signup Successful")
      navigate("/login")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("SIGNUP API ERROR............", error)
      toast.error("Signup Failed")
      navigate("/signup")
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false))
    toast.dismiss(toastId)
  }
}

export function login(email, password, navigate) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const toastId = toast.loading("Loading...")
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    try {
      const response = await apiConnector("POST", LOGIN_API, {
        email,
        password,
      })

      console.log("LOGIN API RESPONSE............", response)

      if (!response.data.success) {
        throw new Error(response.data.message)
      }

      toast.success("Login Successful")
      dispatch(setToken(response.data.token))
      const userImage = response.data?.user?.image
        ? response.data.user.image
        : `https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/initials/svg?seed=${response.data.user.firstName} ${response.data.user.lastName}`
      //dispatch(setUser({ ...response.data.user, image: userImage }))
      
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data.token))
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data.user))
      navigate("/dashboard/my-profile")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("LOGIN API ERROR............", error)
      toast.error("Login Failed")
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false))
    toast.dismiss(toastId)
  }
}

export function logout(navigate) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setToken(null))
    //dispatch(setUser(null))
    //dispatch(resetCart())
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
    localStorage.removeItem("user")
    toast.success("Logged Out")
    navigate("/")
  }
}



export function getPasswordResetToken(email , setEmailSent) {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    try{
      const response = await apiConnector("POST", RESETPASSTOKEN_API, {email,})

      console.log("RESET PASSWORD TOKEN RESPONSE....", response);

      if(!response.data.success) {
        throw new Error(response.data.message);
      }

      toast.success("Reset Email Sent");
      setEmailSent(true);
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log("RESET PASSWORD TOKEN Error", error);
      toast.error("Failed to send email for resetting password");
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false));
  }
}

export function resetPassword(password, confirmPassword, token) {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    try{
      const response = await apiConnector("POST", RESETPASSWORD_API, {password, confirmPassword, token});

      console.log("RESET Password RESPONSE ... ", response);


      if(!response.data.success) {
        throw new Error(response.data.message);
      }

      toast.success("Password has been reset successfully");
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log("RESET PASSWORD TOKEN Error", error);
      toast.error("Unable to reset password");
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false));
  }
}

my signup form
import { useState } from "react"
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast"
import { AiOutlineEye, AiOutlineEyeInvisible } from "react-icons/ai"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

import { sendOtp } from "../../../services/operations/authAPI"
import { setSignupData } from "../../../slices/authSlice"
//import { ACCOUNT_TYPE } from "../../../utils/constants"
//import Tab from "../../common/Tab"

function SignupForm() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  // student or instructor
  //const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState(ACCOUNT_TYPE.STUDENT)

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  })

  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
  const [showConfirmPassword, setShowConfirmPassword] = useState(false)

  const { firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword } = formData

  // Handle input fields, when some value changes
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }))
  }

  // Handle Form Submission
  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      toast.error("Passwords Do Not Match")
      return
    }
    const signupData = {
      ...formData,
     // accountType,
    }

    // Setting signup data to state
    // To be used after otp verification
    dispatch(setSignupData(signupData))
    // Send OTP to user for verification
    dispatch(sendOtp(formData.email, navigate))

    // Reset
    setFormData({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    })
    //setAccountType(ACCOUNT_TYPE.STUDENT)
  }

  // data to pass to Tab component
  const tabData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      tabName: "Student",
      //type: ACCOUNT_TYPE.STUDENT,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      tabName: "Instructor",
      //type: ACCOUNT_TYPE.INSTRUCTOR,
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Tab */}
      {/* <Tab tabData={tabData} field={accountType} setField={setAccountType} /> */}
      {/* Form */}
      <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className="flex w-full flex-col gap-y-4">
        <div className="flex gap-x-4">
          <label>
            <p className="mb-1 text-[0.875rem] leading-[1.375rem] text-richblack-5">
              First Name <sup className="text-pink-200">*</sup>
            </p>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              placeholder="Enter first name"
              style={{
                boxShadow: "inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18)",
              }}
              className="w-full rounded-[0.5rem] bg-richblack-800 p-[12px] text-richblack-5"
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            <p className="mb-1 text-[0.875rem] leading-[1.375rem] text-richblack-5">
              Last Name <sup className="text-pink-200">*</sup>
            </p>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              placeholder="Enter last name"
              style={{
                boxShadow: "inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18)",
              }}
              className="w-full rounded-[0.5rem] bg-richblack-800 p-[12px] text-richblack-5"
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <label className="w-full">
          <p className="mb-1 text-[0.875rem] leading-[1.375rem] text-richblack-5">
            Email Address <sup className="text-pink-200">*</sup>
          </p>
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            placeholder="Enter email address"
            style={{
              boxShadow: "inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18)",
            }}
            className="w-full rounded-[0.5rem] bg-richblack-800 p-[12px] text-richblack-5"
          />
        </label>
        <div className="flex gap-x-4">
          <label className="relative">
            <p className="mb-1 text-[0.875rem] leading-[1.375rem] text-richblack-5">
              Create Password <sup className="text-pink-200">*</sup>
            </p>
            <input
              required
              type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
              name="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              style={{
                boxShadow: "inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18)",
              }}
              className="w-full rounded-[0.5rem] bg-richblack-800 p-[12px] pr-10 text-richblack-5"
            />
            <span
              onClick={() => setShowPassword((prev) => !prev)}
              className="absolute right-3 top-[38px] z-[10] cursor-pointer"
            >
              {showPassword ? (
                <AiOutlineEyeInvisible fontSize={24} fill="#AFB2BF" />
              ) : (
                <AiOutlineEye fontSize={24} fill="#AFB2BF" />
              )}
            </span>
          </label>
          <label className="relative">
            <p className="mb-1 text-[0.875rem] leading-[1.375rem] text-richblack-5">
              Confirm Password <sup className="text-pink-200">*</sup>
            </p>
            <input
              required
              type={showConfirmPassword ? "text" : "password"}
              name="confirmPassword"
              value={confirmPassword}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              style={{
                boxShadow: "inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18)",
              }}
              className="w-full rounded-[0.5rem] bg-richblack-800 p-[12px] pr-10 text-richblack-5"
            />
            <span
              onClick={() => setShowConfirmPassword((prev) => !prev)}
              className="absolute right-3 top-[38px] z-[10] cursor-pointer"
            >
              {showConfirmPassword ? (
                <AiOutlineEyeInvisible fontSize={24} fill="#AFB2BF" />
              ) : (
                <AiOutlineEye fontSize={24} fill="#AFB2BF" />
              )}
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="mt-6 rounded-[8px] bg-yellow-50 py-[8px] px-[12px] font-medium text-richblack-900"
        >
          Create Account
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignupForm

sendotp contoller which works perfectly fine on postman
exports.sendOTP = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email} = req.body;

    const checkUserPresent = await User.findOne({email});

    if (checkUserPresent) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: "User already exist",
      });
    }

    //generate otp

    var otp = OTPgenerator.generate(6, {
      upperCaseAlphabets: false,
      lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
      specialChars: false,
    });
    console.log("OTP generated", otp);

    let result = await OTP.findOne({ otp: otp });
    while (result) {
      otp = OTPgenerator.generate(6, {
        upperCaseAlphabets: false,
        lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
        specialChars: false,
      });
      const result = await OTP.findOne({ otp: otp });
    }

    const otpPayload = { email, otp };

    //create an entry in db

    const otpBody = await OTP.create(otpPayload);
    console.log(otpBody);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "OTP sent successfully",
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: e.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your env file must be missing that would be containing Base Url make sure to create a .env file and store required Backend URL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).